# How to dynamically populate a div from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I'm trying to build a search platform.
On the search results page, I already have three static divs containing the same code to display some contents.

Something like;

```html
<div id="result" class="card">
<img src="hello.png" class="card_img" alt="result image">
<h4>OFFLINE</h4>
<p>Yes!!</p>
</div>

<div id="result" class="card">
<img src="hello.png" class="card_img" alt="result image">
<h4>OFFLINE</h4>
<p>Yes!!</p>
</div>

<div id="result" class="card">
<img src="hello.png" class="card_img" alt="result image">
<h4>OFFLINE</h4>
<p>Yes!!</p>
</div>
```

How do I loop the contents in this div to become dynamic so once a user hits a button;

```html
<button id="search" class="btn" value="Search">
```

The contents in this div loops, so I don't have to keep adding static divs.
How do I make it dynamic with JavaScript?

---

**EDIT**

I am now wondering how to populate a `div` with children matching the contents of the JSON response below? Like a dynamically loaded list:

```
[{
    "name": "Malkov Chicken",
    "location": "New york",
    "meals": 5,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
},
{
    "name": "Delicious Chops",
    "location": "San francisco",
    "meals": 15,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
},
{
    "name": "Banana cultshop",
    "location": "New york",
    "meals": 8,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
}]
```

The div should pass the data from the JSON list, but the div should be looped according to the number of response from the JSON. So if the JSON responds with 5 objects, the divs should be 5.

Comment: Attribute *id* must be unique......also, what do you mean by *I don't have to keep adding static divs*?

Comment: So do you want to add a new card div when you click the button?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes! Basically what I want to do is, once I click the button, contents of the div should loop so I don't have to keep adding divs manually. I want the div to loop

Comment: @GiulioBambini What I mean is so I don't have to add divs manually. The divs hold the same contents, so I would be adding more divs, close to 10 or more so I'm looking for a way to loop just one div to achieve my aim

Comment: Basically I'm fetching my search response from an API. I already have three static divs with the same contents. What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the search button, the divs loop and multiply. I wan't it to be dynamic so I don't have to manually add more divs.

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no sense. Please, clear your problem, construct a reasonable sentence and [edit].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've updated my question

Comment: @BolajiAyodeji Hi, instead of editing your existing question to an entirely new question, please create a new question and enter the new details into that.

Comment: I tried asking a new question but I couldn't because this question was unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to append multiple cards of the same content you can create a general template for one card in javascript, and append multiple of these cards to a container div.

If you wish to append multiple divs of the same content on button click, generate the string outside of the click event using a for loop, and then append the generated string.

Here I named the container div `.content`. Also, note, that each element should have a unique id, and so id's shouldn't be repeated.

See working example below:

```js
let card = 
  `<div class="card">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" class="card_img" alt="result image">
    <h4>OFFLINE</h4>
    <p>Yes!!</p>
   </div>`;

let amount = 10; // amount of cards to add on button click
let toAppend = '';
for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  toAppend += card;
}

$("#search").click(function() {
  $('.content').empty().append(toAppend);  
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content"></div>
<button id="search" class="btn" value="Search">Click me</button>
```

***As per your edited question:***

You can loop through your array of data using `.reduce` and construct a string of separate divs using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). After that, you can append this constructed div to your body or a div (here I have appended it to a div with the class `content`)

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "Malkov Chicken",
    "location": "New york",
    "meals": 5,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
  },
  {
    "name": "Delicious Chops",
    "location": "San francisco",
    "meals": 15,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
  },
  {
    "name": "Banana cultshop",
    "location": "New york",
    "meals": 8,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
  }
];

let html = data.reduce((acc, {name,location, meals, close_time: close}) =>
      acc += `
      <div class='item'>
        <p>${name}</p>
        <p>${location}</p>
        <p>${meals}</p>
        <p>${close}</p>
      </div>`
, ``);

$('.content').append(html);
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: With this, the divs only loop once per click. How do I get it to loop multiple times, let's say 10 per click or more?

Comment: I assume a button named "search" would be for searching the results, not adding new rows. But maybe I don't understand.

Comment: That’s what I originally thought, but when I asked OP if they wanted to add a new card on button click they seemed to say that’s what they were after

Comment: And do you want to add copy these two divs or just one of them when you click a button?

Comment: You should not append N times. Teach to create elements in memory, or concatenate strings - than append only once.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ah, I see. Does my edit imrpove on this?

Comment: Yes. Now by using 10 instead of 3 OP can *loop*-create elements at will. Just as a sidenote - on every click you'll get an incrementing number of divs since .append(). Perhaps .empty() might help... but OP should really clear up his mind on the problem

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Good idea, I've added that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add same HTML element with button click. Please note, you have to use *class* instead of *id* as *id* must be unique in a document.

You can try the following way:

```js
var template = `<div class="result" class="card">
<img src="hello.png" class="card_img" alt="result image">
<h4>OFFLINE</h4>
<p>Yes!!</p>
</div>`;
var occurences = 3;
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click',
function(){
  var strHTML = '';
  for(var i=0; i<occurences; i++){
    strHTML += template;
  }
  document.getElementById('container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', strHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<button id="search" class="btn" value="Search">Create</button>
```

**Update:**

```js
var listArr = [{
    "name": "Malkov Chicken",
    "location": "New york",
    "meals": 5,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
},{
    "name": "Delicious Chops",
    "location": "San francisco",
    "meals": 15,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
},{
    "name": "Banana cultshop",
    "location": "New york",
    "meals": 8,
    "close_time": 1567289876354
}];
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click',
function(){
  var strHTML = '';
  listArr.forEach(function(item){
    strHTML += `<div class="Results-item">
            <h4 class="Results-itemName">${item.name}</h4>
            <p class="Results-itemLocation"><b>${item.location}</b></p>
            <p class="Results-itemDetails">Meals: ${item.meals} Close time: ${item.close_time}</p>
            </div>`;
  })
  document.getElementById('container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', strHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="search" class="btn" value="Search">Create</button>
```

Comment: This works fine, but how do I get it to loop multiple time and not just once? That's my aim

Comment: @BolajiAyodeji, you can use a loop then......I have updated the answer .....please check.

Comment: Don't make DOM accessors in loops. Create elements in-memory or concatenate strings - append only once, after the loop.

Comment: @BolajiAyodeji, do you mean to create div from the list?

Comment: Yes, the div should pass the data from the JSON list, but the div should be looped according to the number of response from the JSON. So if the JSON responds with 5 objects, the divs should be 5. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @GiulioBambini Yes, it works. Thank you! Although I made some modifications to suit my aim.

Answer (score 1):

Given a JSON *Array* of Objects, you could:

- Create a string literal Template
- `.map()` your JSON data into a templater `TPL_Results` function
- Join the mapped result and insert into DOM

```js
const JSON = [{
    "name": "Malkov Chicken",
    "location": "New york",
    "meals": 5,
    "close_time": '23:30'
},{
    "name": "Delicious Chops",
    "location": "San francisco",
    "meals": 15,
    "close_time": '22:00'
},{
    "name": "Banana cultshop",
    "location": "New york",
    "meals": 8,
    "close_time": '23:00'
}];

const TPL_Results = item => `<div class="Results-item">
  <h3 class="Results-itemName">${item.name}</h3>
  <p class="Results-itemLocation"><b>${item.location}</b></p>
  <p class="Results-itemDetails">Meals: ${item.meals} Close time: ${item.close_time}</p>
</div>`;

document.querySelector("#results")
 .innerHTML = JSON.map(item => TPL_Results(item)).join('');
```

```html
<div class="Results" id="results"></div>
```